# Trying to get value of input box not in a form using JQuery

Tags: jquery

Below is some very simple code I put together; trying to learn jquery.  I cannot for the life of me figure out why this does not work.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script>src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="ac3" size="20" value="">
        <br><br>
        <button onclick="getvalue('ac3')">Search</button>

        <script>
            function getvalue(id){
                var txt = $('#'+id).text();
                alert(txt);
            }
        </script>       
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<script>src` should be `<script src`

Comment: My bad, I should have checked my code before posting it .

Answer (score 0):

`$('#'+id).text();` will return the innertext of the element

Use `$('#'+id).val();`

Answer (score 0):

1: your script tag is wrong.  place src=blah inside the tag

(ie <script src="foobar"></script>)

2: init jquery (see below)

3: need to use .val()

here is an approach you might try.  (removes the inline onclick, those are yuck lol)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  

<button data-myvalue="ac3">


(function($) {

     $('button').on('click', function (){
          var myid = '#'+this.data("myvalue");
          alert($(myid).val());
     });

})(jQuery);
```